# Iterate over child pages using xtype pathfield

Tags: java, iterator, aem

I am trying to create a list of all child pages to display as a hyperlinked list. I have the user select the parent folder, and any child pages should be listed accordingly. However, it is coming up blank (`children` is empty).

The dialog element:

```
<listRoot
  name (String): ./listRoot
  jcr:primaryType (Name): cq:Widget
  xtype (String): pathfield
>
```

The source code:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@page
import="java.util.Iterator,
        com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter"
%>
<%@page session="false" %>

<%
    String listroot = properties.get("listRoot", currentPage.getPath());
    Page rootPage = pageManager.getPage(listroot);
    if (rootPage != null) {
        Iterator<Page> children = rootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter(request));
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            Page child = children.next();
            String title = child.getTitle() == null ? child.getName() : child.getTitle();
            String date = child.getProperties().get("date","");
            %><div class="item">
            <a href="<%= child.getPath() %>.html"><b><%= title %></b></a>
            <span><%= date %></span><br>
            <%= child.getProperties().get("jcr:description","") %><br>
            </div><%
        }
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if the child pages have been hidden from navigation ( "hide in navigation" property would have been selected in the page properties ).

Because, using a new [PageFilter(request)](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageFilter.html) would exclude all the hidden pages.

Otherwise this code runs just fine for me.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Thank you for that bit of info. I did not manually set the pages to be hidden from navigation, but apparently they were.

Is there something with the template the are bound to that determine if they are hidden by default? Because all the pages I create otherwise appear after creation.

Comment: You can hide by default by configuring in the template, but am not sure if that is the case here.